# Why does console.log() print a variable in duplicate when placed in a function that renders a view?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have a simple global variable that holds a string in my `app.js` file:

```
global.MyActivity = "peanutbutterjellytime"
```

I have another file `index.js` which is a router/controller. In this file I do this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
console.log(global.MyActivity); // this prints the variable once to the console. Great!

router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    console.log(global.MyActivity); // this prints the variable in duplicate
    res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Activity Page'}); // i think this is causing the problem. if i remove it it works fine
});

module.exports = router;
```

I always comment out the `console.log(global.MyActivity);` outside of the `router.get()` method so I know its not doing a duplicate print because of any appending.

I can't understand why, when rendering a view, does the console print the variable twice whereas if I remove that render code it does it correctly and prints it only once. So this works fine:

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    console.log(global.MyActivity); // this prints once
    console.log("I am sync"); // this prints once
});

router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    console.log(global.MyActivity); // this prints twice!
    console.log("I am async"); // this prints twice!
    res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Activity Page'}); 
});
```

This causes me a problem if I want to send `global.MyActivity` to my view like `res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Activity Page', activity: global.MyActivity})` because it does in duplicate. My view engine is express-handlebars which is just Handlebars.js for Express.

**Update/Fix 1 (fluke, I don't understand why it works)**
Just for kicks I put in a callback function. That fixes the problem of duplicate console logs, but the view never renders.

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    console.log(global.MyActivity); // this prints once now! why?

    res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Activity Page'}, function(){ }); // this never renders 

});
```

Comment: Are you checking the log when calling the route from some browser? Or are you using some tool like postman/curl request

Comment: @AbhishekAnand updated my question. the problem isnt being in the router.get() method, its the async function. If I remove the async then it prints once only

Comment: What is your version of Node js ?@volumeone

Comment: @EmilHotkowski it is the latest v12.13.0. I also updated my question because its not the async causing the issue, its the `res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Activity Page'});` part. If I remove that, then it only prints once to the console which is correct

Comment: Can you check if the problem persists if you don't use callback. render.res.render('index');

Comment: @AbhishekAnand if I just do `render.rs.render("index")` then the problem goes away.  but it means I can't pass data to my view because If I include data like `render.res.render('index', {pagetitle: "hi", data: SomeJSONdata}); then I get errors. Can you please explain whats going on because I am very new to Javascript/Node and dont understand it.

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(req)` to the `router.get` and compare the two requests? This might give a clue as to why it's being called twice. My gut tells me something in the view is calling another request somehow.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction project? I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @bendataclear as soon as i added an empty callback function in the `res.render()` function, it also fixes the problem. why is that?

Comment: @ParrapbanzZ I updated my question with my fix. A fix that I don't even understand. Can you shed some light on why the empty callback helped?

Comment: try this and it should work res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Activity Page'},()=>{});